# Greatest product of consecutive digits

Tags: c, arrays, find

I need to find the greatest product of 10 consecutive digits in the 150-digit number in C but i cant see whats wrong.

I used `nr[]` to store the 10 consecutive numbers and `n`to store the biggest 10 number multiplie.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int array[150]={7,3,1,6,7,1,7,6,5,3,1,3,3,0,6,2,4,9,1,9,2,2,5,1,1,9,6,7,4,4,2,6,5,7,4,7,4,2,3,5,5,3,4,9,1,9,4,9,3,4,9,6,9,8,3,5,2,0,3,1,2,7,7,4,5,0,6,3,2,6,2,3,9,5,7,8,3,1,8,0,1,6,9,8,4,8,0,1,8,6,9,4,7,8,8,5,1,8,4,3,8,5,8,6,1,5,6,0,7,8,9,1,1,2,9,4,9,4,9,5,4,5,9,5,0,1,7,3,7,9,5,8,3,3,1,9,5,2,8,5,3,2,0,8,8,0,5,5,1,1};
    int i,l,j,nr[10];
    long int n=1,k;
    for(i=0;i<140;i++){
        k=1;
        for(j=i;j<i+10;j++){
            k=k*array[j];
        }
        if(n<k){
            for(l=0;l<10;l++){
                nr[l]=array[i+l];
            }
            n=k;
        }
        for(i=0;i<=9;i++){
            printf("%d ",nr[i]); 
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it build? Does it run and not work as expected (and if so, in what way)?

Comment: Oh, and perhaps move the question into the question itself rather than the subject

Comment: You shouldn’t need to calculate the product from scratch each iteration.  If P is the product for X[n]..X[n+9], then the product for X[n+1]..X[n+10] is P / X[n] * X[n+10].  Also, a zero allows you to skip completely past it.

Comment: Use meaningful variable names.

Answer (score 1):

try`for(i=1;i<=150;i++);`
because you need 150-digit number

Comment: No, for example the string `{"7", "3", "5"}` only has strings of 2 digits starting at 0 and 1

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem you have is that you have a `return` inside your outer `for` loop. That means you'll be exitting from your loop after you've looked at the first batch of 10 numbers.

You also have a problem in that you're printing your `nr` array inside your outer loop, so it will print a lot of stuff. You probably want it outside, just before your return.

Fixing those gives a string of:

```
9 4 9 4 9 5 4 5 9 5
```

I haven't checked, but there's a lot of 9's in there and nothing smaller than 4 so can easily imagine it's the largest string once multiplied.

Comment: Omg thanks so much i cant believe i lost so much time and didnt notice...